# Pause code untill a button is pressed

Tags: arduino-uno

I need some code to pause the Arduino code until a button is pressed. I have a long program and at point I need a condition that if a Button on pin A2 is pressed then go forward, otherwise wait.

I tried using `if` with a condition but it failed for my purpose. I think this is because when `if(...)` detects that the button is not pressed, it moves to next lines (as usual). But I have a long program and I want to wait forever until the button is pressed.

Comment: Is it active high or active low (are you using pullup or pulldown resistors)?

Comment: See my edit please. I am just using a Pushbutton with a resistor. I tested the button with different programs. It all works fine.

Comment: You haven't answered my question though.  Is the resistor connected to +5V or to GND? It makes a big difference to the code snippet I will spoon feed you.

Comment: The resistor is connected to Ground. Help me

Answer (score 3):

The construct you are looking for is called `while`.

Instead of doing "If the button is pressed then continue" you need to do "while the button is not pressed do nothing".

Assuming you have an "active low" button (that is, a resistor pulling it up to +5V when not pressed, so `digitalRead(A2) == LOW` is "pressed"), you can do:

```
while (digitalRead(A2) == HIGH) {
  // Do nothing
}
```

So while it's not pressed (`digitalRead(A2) == HIGH`) don't do anything.  As soon as `digitalRead(A2)` returns LOW (so it is not `== HIGH` any more) the `while` loop will finish and your sketch can continue.

I write all about the `while` loop in an article [here](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/while-loop).

Comment: will it continue right from where it has stopped..? Lets say if my motor is at 67 degrees it should resume from the same. Is it doing the same..?

Answer (score 2):

> I need a code to pause arduino code until a button is pressed.

I wrote a simple [function](https://gist.github.com/rahuldottech/839cb13140f24debae8f72343115de4b) to do this.

#### Usage:

```
buttonWait(<pin_number>);
```

#### Code:

```
/* the function */
void buttonWait(int buttonPin){
  int buttonState = 0;
  while(1){
    buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
      return;
    }
  }
}


void loop() {
  buttonWait(2); // wait for button press on pin 2
  // do something
  // ...
}
```

This code assumes that you have a pulldown resistor, but you can easily modify it to work with a pullup resistor instead, if you feel the need:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDTfwv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

See example code [here](https://gist.github.com/rahuldottech/839cb13140f24debae8f72343115de4b)!

Comment: Thank you rahuldottech!! I had been fussing with my code for several months on and off and tonight...I hit gold!!

Comment: @Osprey That's great to hear! :)

Comment: The battery doesn't make sense in that circuit. you have it wired to use +5V from VCC, which is correct, but why have a battery hooked to +5V? (Unless you are planning to bypass the internal regulator and the battery is really a regulated 5V supply?)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways you might have wired the button. If you wired it with a pullup, you will need to test for LOW (the button will ground its output when pressed). If pulldown, the button will raise its output when pressed and you would test for HIGH.

If you will be testing the button again within less than a second, don't forget to debounce it. Switches send a bunch (technical term :) of pulses for a significant fraction of a second during a make or bread. See Nick Gammon's ["Switches" page](http://www.gammon.com.au/switches) for a thorough discussion.

[image: Pullup vs. Pulldown Schematic]

Answer (score -1):

Pausing a program can be accomplished using Light Sleep mode as demonstrated in given URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIbSt5mJ5VY

Comment: Welcome to Arduino! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.